# OutputCache attribute and jQuery Ajax not caching

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, outputcache

I have a simple MVC3 Controller Action like this

```
[HttpGet]
[OutputCache(Duration = 1200,Location=System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
public string GetTheDate()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

And I call it from jQuery Ajax like this

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:60690/Public/GetTheDate",
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                //alert("success");
                jQuery("#stats").append("<b>" + data + "</b>");
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) { alert("failure"); alert(error + " " + status + " " + req); }
        });
```

The problem is that the date is always the current date, not the cached response. My understanding was that `[OutputCache( Location=Server)]` means that the server (the MVC app) caches the response and when the client requests the data, the action is intercepted so as not to bother with `DateTime.Now` but returns the cached response.

Am I understanding it wrongly or simply doing something wrong?

**Update :**

3nigma's answer is right. `VaryByParams="none"` does the trick but..... It's obvious from my method that I don't have any parameters so why should I need to say "none". Turns out that the 'Params' I was thinking the documentation referred to were params in my method are actually not the params in my method, they are anything that the request handler could construe as params.

The [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.outputcacheparameters.varybyparam.aspx) says

> When this property is set to multiple parameters, the output cache
>   contains a different version of the requested document for each
>   specified parameter. Possible values include "none", "*", and **any
>   valid query string** or POST parameter name.

See the bit in bold (my emphasis) that means that although I'm not expecting any querystring parameters, if any get sent in (like the way jQuery.ajax does when cache:false by appending to the request `GET /Public/GetTheDate?_=1324047171837` ) then there is a parameter, whether I expected it or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

with `cache: false,` you are explicitly telling jquery not to cache set   `cache: true,`

Edit

set the `VaryByParam="none"` like

```
[OutputCache(Duration=1200, VaryByParam="none",Location=System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
```

Comment: But doesn't that only say 'don't cache on the client-side'. I mean the client always sends the request but OutputCache(location=server) says something along the lines of 'service the request as normal (from the outside) but instead of doing what's in the action just return the cached result'. No?

Comment: yes caching on the server means if the same request comes from someother user instead of going through the action it will be served the cached result

Comment: try `[OutputCache(Duration=1200, VaryByParam="none",Location=System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
` here is a useful link http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

Comment: I had read that page and although they use `VaryByParam="none"` it never dawned on me that it's a requirement to have it defined even when you have no parameters - certainly isn't mentioned in the documentation. That's done the trick, still with client side `cache : false`. It's nice to know I was right, while still being wrong !

Comment: can you update your 'proper' answer to reflect the real fix and I'll green-up your tick. Thanks.