# ASP .Net MVC 5 JsonResult caching

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-mvc-5

can someone explain me how to implement caching of `JsonResult` actions in MVC 5 application?
I want to use caching of some `ajax`-called actions using `[OutputCache()]`  attribute. Some of these actions return `ActionResult` with `html`-content, some `JsonResult` with serialized lists of `{Id, Title}` pairs which I'm going to use to construct dropdown lists.

My goal is to reduce amount of DB-queries (while building ViewModels) and server requests (when using ajax-calls for it).

So, my code looks like snippets below:

```
[OutputCache(Duration=60*60*24)]
public async Task<ActionResult> SearchCaseOrgDialog(){
    //extract data return html page
    return View();
}

[OutputCache(Duration=60*60*24)]
public async Task<JsonResult> AjaxOrgDepartments(){
    //query database, serialize data, return json
    var result = await ctx.OrgDepartments
                          .Select(d => new { 
                                        Id = d.Id, 
                                        Title =  d.Title }
                                 )
                          .ToListAsync();

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When I look at FireFox tools-panel I see next picture for `Html`-content:
[image: FF caching html content]

Here Firefox uses client-side cached version of `ajax`-requested page.

But situation differs with `json`-content:
[image: FF doesn't cache json content]

It doesn't cache content, and seems to transfer data from server (server-side cache).

In both cases response headers look the same:

```
Cache-Control:"public, max-age=86400, s-maxage=0"
```

Content is requested using similar `ajax`-calls like

```
$.get(url, null, function(data){
    //do something with data
});
```

So, how do I cache json-content? what is the right way to do it, and why default approach does not work?

Comment: Do other browsers respect the cache headers? Seems FF ignores this for AJAX requests. You could also use the ObjectCache (`HttpContext.Current.Cache`) to store the result from a query.

Comment: @Jasen, actually when I open link directly in browser (without `ajax`) result is the same anyway. In Chrome situation also looks similar

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535160/outputcache-attribute-and-jquery-ajax-not-caching

Comment: @Edward in that question there is a problem with server-side caching. In my case server side caching works well. There is something with client-side: browser asks server and gets cached server result, but it doesnt use its own cache

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid DB queries, you should consider caching the data at server side. You can use [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) class to do that.

Quick sample

```
public class MyLookupDataCache
{
    const string categoryCacheKey = "CATEGORYLIST";
    public List<string> GetCategories()
    {
        var cache = MemoryCache.Default;
        var items = cache.Get(categoryCacheKey);
        if (items != null)
        {
            CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
            policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7); //7 days 
            //Now query from db
            List<string> newItems = repository.GetCategories();
            cache.Set(categoryCacheKey, newItems, policy);
            return newItems;
        }
        else
        {
            return (List<string>) items;
        }
    }
}
```

You can change the method signature to return the type you want. For simplicity, i am using `List<String>`